# How to calculate the cross correlation between two time series measured at different instants?

Tags: time-series, cross-correlation, unevenly-spaced-time-series

I have two time series with measurements of the same type but different stations. I would like to know if the two series are correlated and how much is the "lag" between them. The idea is that in this way I would be able to predict the behavior of a station looking at the other. I have investigated a bit, and I think that the tool I need is the cross correlation. But how can I calculate the cross correlation between two time series if the samples are taken at different instants?

The timespan is the same, let's say Monday to Sunday, but the samples are taken at completely different instants and for a certain `t` I don't always have a value for both series.

How should I do in this case? All cross correlation formulas require you to have both `y(t)` and `z(t)`, if `y` and `z` are the two series.

Comment: I've faced similar problems in the past, but can't say I have a completely satisfactory answer.  Can you put them on approximately the same intervals by taking a subset of one of the timeseries?  Not that great an answer, you are losing information.

Comment: You mean I could create the "missing" values on a timeserie by using subset of values and calculating the mean?

Comment: The mean could work.  Even better might be (depending on the process's variability) to pick the value from the time series with the shorter intervals that is closest to the measurement time on the time series with larger intervals.  Depends on the process, of course.  For example, suppose timeseries A is measured once a day at noon.  Timeseries B, once an hour.  Take the values of timeseries B at noon for each day, discard the rest.  However, not sure if this is your situation / others may have better ideas that salvage more info from timeseries B.

Comment: This gives me an idea. I could calculate the cross-correlation on the moving averages. The samples are taken every 5 minutes for every station. I could calculate the moving averages using a window of 1 Hour, and then cross-correlate the result. Could this be a good approach?

Comment: Depends on the process. Ideally (at least in the formulation we're discussing), you're trying to approximate taking a reading at the same time in timeseries_a as in timeseries_b.  So, if you're trying to make timeseries_a match the intervals of timeseries_b, the best approach will be domain / dataset specific.  By this I mean, would a rolling average more closely help you match up these two timeseries?  Or would just taking the closest available measurements in time?

Comment: Did this answer your question @Enrico? If it does, I'll summarize my responses into an answer, if you don't mind accepting the answer.

Comment: Yes please summarize everything into an answer, I'll accept it. You helped me a lot, I'll definitely go for one of the two approaches.

Comment: Thanks @Enrico.  Glad to hear it was of help.  I've summarized below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is a domain/process specific problem of approximating the expected values for one of the processes (`process_a`) at the time intervals of measurement of `process_b`.  A few options, in order of increasing sophistication:

1. Take the values of `timeseries_a` that are closest in time to those observed in `timeseries_b`.  Assumption: the best approximation of  `process_a` at time `t` is that of the closest measurement in time of `process_a`.
2. Approximate the values of `timeseries_a` at the time of measurement of `timeseries_b` using a weighted average.  Assumption: the best approximation of `process_a` at time `t` is the weighted average of the measurements of `process_a` around that time.
3. Model `process_a` more fully as a regression problem, and make an estimate of the values at the same measurement times as `process_b`. Assumptions: whatever the assumptions of your models are.

Very open to other's answers as well!